# jQuery get() working on localhost, but not working on remote server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm currently developing a jQuery application on my local computer. I'm using a LAMP server to develop. What I'm trying to do is when clicked on a button, a jQuery $.get() AJAX request should be called and it should load some content from an external .txt file into the current page.

Here's my main HTML page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <!-- some extra head tags are here -->
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="a">
      <!-- extra content of div with class "a" -->
      <img src="img/beaver.png" alt="Play">
    </div>

    <script src="jquery/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here's my jQuery script page (script.js):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".a img").click(function(){
    $.get("text_file.txt", function(x, y){
      $(".a").after(x);
    });
  });
});
```

Finally, my text_file.txt page:

```
<div class="b">
  <!-- content of div with class "b" -->
</div>
```

When I run this on my localhost (e.g. http://localhost/index.html), the script works fine. But when I uploaded this onto a remote server via FTP, and then access the file, it doesn't work. It doesn't even show any error messages in the console. What could be wrong?

Thank you,
Abraar

Comment: Can you share the link to take a look?

Comment: Have you tried a hard refresh or incognito/private window? Could be that your JS is cached

Comment: Does the cross-origin policy prohibit the access?

Comment: We need to see the URLs you are using and your file structure for both local and remote.  What does your browser console say?  Any errors? 404?

Comment: Look at the request in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a slash at the beggining of the url where you are performing the request in order to make it relative to your script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".a img").click(function(){
    $.get("/text_file.txt", function(x, y){
      $(".a").after(x);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Your solution works, but it turns out that I actually need to use an .html file instead of an .txt file. As I'm loading HTML code, I used .html file and it works. Thanks!

Comment: @Abraar Arique: Please note that this solution will not work if you ever host you application as a web application under a non-root path.

Answer (score 0):

The html file is running in a browser on your local machine.
When you do the $.get() it's probably getting confused where the file is, since it is up on the server.  You'd have to give it the address of the file "https://server.com/text_file.txt" where server.com is the address for your server.

Comment: You would not normally reference a file on the same server via an absolute URL. Relative or root-relative would be the normal methods.

Answer (score -2):

Right  from the JQuery documentation on $.get()

> If a request with jQuery.get() returns an error code, it will fail silently unless the script has also called the global .ajaxError() method. Alternatively, as of jQuery 1.5, the .error() method of the jqXHR object returned by jQuery.get() is also available for error handling.

Comment: What is wrong with this?  I'm sure that the error message would have been revealed by the ajaxError method